# Add `RasterLayer` to `addLayersControl` in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, geospatial, raster

I have to `RasterLayer`-objects (`raster1` and `raster2`) in R. And I want to add them both to a leaflet-map. I also wanted to have the option to show or hide them. So I thought I'd add them with their names to the `addLayersControl`-option. But it doesn't work. It shows both layers at the same time and I can't hide them. So far my code looks like this. I think the problem is in how to add them to the `addLayersControl`-function.

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addRasterImage(raster1, opacity = 0.3) %>% 
  addRasterImage(raster2, opacity = 0.3) %>% 
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)"),
    overlayGroups = c("raster1", "raster2"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  )
```

I guess that's kind of easy,but I can't think of any sollution.

Answer (score 1):

From the `addLayersControl` [help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.0.3/topics/addLayersControl):

> **overlayGroups**
>   character vector where each element is the name of a **group**. The user can turn **each overlay group** on or off independently.

So you need groups. From the `addRasterImage` [help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.0.3/topics/addRasterImage):

> **group**
>   the name of the group this raster image should belong to (see the same parameter under addTiles)

Your code need to be something like this:

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addRasterImage(raster1, opacity = 0.3, group = 'raster1') %>% 
  addRasterImage(raster2, opacity = 0.3, group = 'raster2') %>% 
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)"),
    overlayGroups = c("raster1", "raster2"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  )
```